# std::complex multiplication is extremely slow

Tags: gcc, std

I have noticed that multiplying two `std::complex` values is much, much slower using the overloaded `*` operator than writing out the operation. I've seen a 50x difference. That is totally ridiculous. I understand that the operator needs to check for NaN in the input, because of how complex infinity is defined. Can that really account for a 50x time difference?

I'm using GCC 5.4.0 with the flags `-O3 -mavx -mavx2 -msse2 -mfma -mbmi`.

Here's the test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

int main( void ) {
  size_t N = 10000;
  std::vector< std::complex< double >> inbuf( N );
  for( size_t k = 0; k < N; ++k ) {
     inbuf[ k ] = std::complex< double >( std::rand(), std::rand() ) / ( double )RAND_MAX - 0.5;
  }

  std::complex< double > c2 = { 0, 0 };
  auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for( size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i ) {
     for( size_t j = 0; j < N - 1; ++j ) {
        double re = inbuf[ j ].real() * inbuf[ j + 1 ].real() - inbuf[ j ].imag() * inbuf[ j + 1 ].imag();
        double im = inbuf[ j ].real() * inbuf[ j + 1 ].imag() + inbuf[ j ].imag() * inbuf[ j + 1 ].real();
        c2.real( c2.real() + re );
        c2.imag( c2.imag() + im );
     }
  }
  auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  double time = ( std::chrono::duration< float >( t1 - t0 ) ).count();
  std::cout << c2 << " using manual *: " << time << std::endl;

  c2 = { 0, 0 };
  t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for( size_t i = 0; i < 10000; ++i ) {
     for( size_t j = 0; j < N - 1; ++j ) {
        c2 += inbuf[ j ] * inbuf[ j + 1 ];
     }
  }
  t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  time = ( std::chrono::duration< float >( t1 - t0 ) ).count();
  std::cout << c2 << " using stdlib *: " << time << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
(-2.45689e+07,-134386) using manual *: 0.109344
(-2.45689e+07,-134386) using stdlib *: 5.4286
```

---

Edit: Given the different results by folks in the comments, I have done a bit more testing with various compile options. It turns out that the `-mfma` and the `-mavx` switches cause the "stdlib" version to be so slow. The `-mfma` switch gives the "manual" version a ~25% performance boost, but slows down the "stdlib" version about 13x:

```
cris@carrier:~/tmp/tests> g++ complex_test.cpp -o complex_test -O3 -std=c++11
cris@carrier:~/tmp/tests> ./complex_test                                     
(-2.45689e+07,-134386) using manual *:0.138276
(-2.45689e+07,-134386) using stdlib *:0.412056
cris@carrier:~/tmp/tests> g++ complex_test.cpp -o complex_test -O3 -mfma -std=c++11 
cris@carrier:~/tmp/tests> ./complex_test                                                  
(-2.45689e+07,-134386) using manual *:0.106551
(-2.45689e+07,-134386) using stdlib *:5.37662
```

I also tried clang-800 (Mac OS) and didn't see this extreme slow-down. g++-5 on Mac does the same as g++-5 on Linux. Maybe I've found a compiler bug?

Comment: One way to test your theory is to include tests with `std::isnan` in your manual method.  Curious to know your timings.  I have certainly come across problems with NAN-testing (and taking appropriate action) in production code, which I ended up optimizing with Intel Intrinsics.

Comment: Without -ffast-math or other, complex multiplication yields a call to the function __muldc3 from libgcc. That adds some overhead for placing values in the right registers before the call, and for the call itself. The function __muldc3 seems to compute the real and imaginary parts in the obvious way, then checks isnan(real)&&isnan(imag) and unless that triggers it is done and returns. A large overhead compared to the -ffast-math case is not surprising, though a factor 50 does seem higher than I would have expected. PS: please don't skip parts (like #include) of the testcase.

Comment: And indeed I am seeing a much smaller ratio here (8 with gcc-7, only 2.5 with gcc-5). Are you on windows by any chance?

Comment: I'm on Linux.

I'm surprised that both real and imaginary parts are checked for NaN. If any one input component is NaN, both output components will be NaN. NaN does not result from multiplication or addition/subtraction unless the input is NaN, or?

Comment: Interesting. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae8711afa33bdbe6) is a naive `isnan` check included which still leads to a factor of 2 in execution time.

Comment: 0 times infinity and infinity minus infinity yield NaN. When the multiplication is done inline (as opposed to with a function call), further optimizations (like vectorization) are possible, which can also help explain the higher ratio (that I could not reproduce).

Answer (score 2):

This post worried me greatly! Use -O3 and -ffast-math (or -Ofast), and the differences go away.

[gcc differences between -O3 vs -Ofast optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232427/gcc-differences-between-o3-vs-ofast-optimizations)

Straight:

> g++    -std=c++11  timingComplex.cpp && ./a.out
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using manual *: 5.20456
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using stdlib *: 4.02066

Ofast:

> g++  -Ofast  -std=c++11  timingComplex.cpp && ./a.out
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using manual *: 0.154484
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using stdlib *: 0.155045

O3:

> g++  -O3  -std=c++11  timingComplex.cpp &&  ./a.out
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using manual *: 0.193446
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using stdlib *: 0.350336

O3 + ffast-math:

> g++  -O3 -ffast-math  -std=c++11  timingComplex.cpp &&  ./a.out
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using manual *: 0.154603
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using stdlib *: 0.156592

ffast-math:

> g++  -ffast-math  -std=c++11  timingComplex.cpp &&  ./a.out
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using manual *: 5.17364
> (-2.50606e+07,-29494.2) using stdlib *: 4.0194

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, apparently slow performance of complex calculations within visual C++. In my case it turned out, that I did the time measurements in debug mode of visual C++. After switching to release mode, the times are reasonable compared to double calculations (considering that a complex manipulation includes several double calculations).