# gcc differences between -O3 vs -Ofast optimizations

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization

I was just reading through the gcc manual to find out the difference between `-O3` and `-Ofast`.

For `-O3`

> -O3
>
> ```
> Optimize yet more. -O3 turns on all optimizations specified by -O2 and also turns on the following optimization flags:
>
> -fgcse-after-reload 
> -fipa-cp-clone
> -floop-interchange 
> -floop-unroll-and-jam 
> -fpeel-loops 
> -fpredictive-commoning 
> -fsplit-paths 
> -ftree-loop-distribute-patterns 
> -ftree-loop-distribution 
> -ftree-loop-vectorize 
> -ftree-partial-pre 
> -ftree-slp-vectorize 
> -funswitch-loops 
> -fvect-cost-model 
> -fversion-loops-for-strides
> ```

While of `-Ofast`

> -Ofast
>
> ```
> Disregard strict standards compliance. -Ofast enables all -O3 optimizations. It also enables optimizations that are not valid for
> all standard-compliant programs. It turns on -ffast-math,
> -fallow-store-data-races and the Fortran-specific -fstack-arrays, unless -fmax-stack-var-size is specified, and -fno-protect-parens
> ```

Therefore I was wondering, if maybe `-Ofast` is for some reason less safe than `-O3`, and therefore I should stick to `-O3` most of the times then.

Can you clarify the "practical difference" when using them? And if `-Ofast` is actually safe?

Answer (score 33):

`Ofast` enables optimizations which violate requirements of C standard for floating-point semantics. In particular under `-Ofast` (aka `-ffast-math`) it'll freely reorder float computations (which is prohibited by default because in general `a + (b + c) != (a + b) + c != (a + c) + b` for floats).

Whether `-Ofast` is safe in particular case depends on the algorithm but *usually* most non-scientific applications work fine with it. For example most game engines are built with `-ffast-math`.

EDIT:

Since 2021 `-Ofast` in GCC also enables `-fno-semantic-interposition` which is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48521068/2170527).

Comment: And nowadays also `-fallow-store-data-races` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html